# How to count each month without repeating the lines?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create all months in a query instead of use several lines.

Here is the information:

```
CREATE TABLE quotes (
  id INT,
  created_at DATE,
  num_policy INT);

INSERT INTO quotes VALUES
 (   1,     '2014-01-01',1234),      
 (   2,     '2014-02-06',5678),  
 (   3,     '2013-04-24',9123), 
 (   4,     '2013-05-24',4567),
 (   5,     '2014-06-20',8912);
```

I tried this query:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f4f51/5

```
SET @year := 2014;

SELECT count(*) AS jan FROM `quotes` WHERE (created_at BETWEEN CONCAT( @year, "-01-01") AND CONCAT( @year, "-01-31")) ;
SELECT count(*) AS feb FROM `quotes` WHERE (created_at BETWEEN CONCAT( @year, "-02-01") AND CONCAT( @year, "-02-29")) ;
......

SELECT count(*) AS dem FROM `quotes` WHERE (created_at BETWEEN CONCAT( @year, "-12-01") AND CONCAT( @year, "-12-31")) ;
```

I'm trying to show all months in one line

```
  |jan|  |feb|  |mar|  |apr| ......
    1       1      0     0
```

Please somebody can help me?

I will appreciate all kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could do the magic:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MonthSET @year := 2014;

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Month(created_at) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS jan,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Month(created_at) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS feb,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Month(created_at) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS mar,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Month(created_at) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS apr,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Month(created_at) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS may,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Month(created_at) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS jun,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Month(created_at) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS jul,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Month(created_at) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS aug,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Month(created_at) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sep,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Month(created_at) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS oct,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Month(created_at) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nov,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Month(created_at) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `dec`
FROM `quotes` 
WHERE YEAR(created_at) = @year
```

Link to a SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f4f51/13/1

Answer (score 1):

How about using `group by`?

```
SELECT month(created_at), count(*) AS cnt
FROM `quotes`
WHERE (created_at BETWEEN CONCAT( @year, "-01-01") AND CONCAT( @year, "-01-31"))
GROUP BY month(created_at)
ORDER BY 1;
```

This does produce the values on separate lines.  To get them on one line, use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(month(created_at) = 1) as jan,
       SUM(month(created_at) = 2) as feb,
       . . .
FROM quotes
;WHERE (created_at BETWEEN CONCAT( @year, '-01-01') AND CONCAT( @year, '-01-31'));
```